# How to properly ignore windows created by Visual Studio debugging tool for XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

In my application I need to get a list of all windows.

```
var windows = Application.Current.Windows;
```

If I run my application in debug mode I see not only my forms in the list, but also instances of `Microsoft.XamlDiagnostics.WpfTap.WpfVisualTreeService.Adorners.AdornerLayerWindow` created by Visual Studio debugging tool for XAML.

What is the right way to filter list of windows to ignore windows created by debugging tool? I don't want to reference additional assembly and check if

```
window is AdornerLayerWindow
```

and I don't want to filter like

```
window.GetType().Name != "AdornerLayerWindow"
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just switch them off under *Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML*?

Comment: Of course I can switch off debugging tool. In this case I'll not be able to use this tools and all other developers who work on this project will have to switch this tools off. Every time new developer join the project I'll have to inform that debugging tool should be switched off. I don't think that it is a right way of doing things.

Comment: In my case switching off the UI Debugging Tools turned out to be the better of two evils. Thanks @Clemens!

Comment: For VS 2019:
Tools-> Options -> Debugging -> Hot Reload -> Enable XAML hot reload

Answer (score 0):

I just do the trick `window.ActualWidth != 0`. It works good for me.

```cs
Application.Current.Windows
    .Cast<Window>()
    .Where(w => w.ActualWidth != 0)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(w => w.Close());
```